# Energy settings with dconf Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, 18.04, dconf, gsettings, gnome-control-center

The energy settings for "Blank screen" is set default on 5 minutes. You can edit them with the gnome-control-center, but I would like to have some dconf / gsettings to change the value.

It's about the following setting I would like to change with dconf:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associated `dconf` path for `idle-delay` key is `/org/gnome/desktop/session/`. So you can manipulate it for example using `gsettings` as follows

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay <PREFERRED-VALUE-IN-SECONDS>
```

Comment: Thank you @Pomsky. Is it correct after changing the dconf value that the settings still show you something different?

Comment: @Sander The drop-down list in Settings app has limited options, so it may show something wrong. For example if you set the time to say 1 hour, it would show "never" as there is no entry between "15 minutes" and "never".

Comment: that's right. After changing the value to 900 with gsettings it show 15 minutes in the dropdown. Thank you again for your help.